# Problems with digital input of ESI Juli@ xte PCI Soundcard

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard

I've got an [ESI Juli@ xte PCI Soundcard](http://www.esi-audio.com/products/juliaxte/) and want to use it on Ubuntu 12.04 Server. It's going to be a capture device only. It's used in a small free radio station. I want to use two analog inputs to capture the live radio program and the digital spdif (coaxial) in for streaming via darkice (icecast2 client) at the same time.

I got the analog inputs working well with arecord, but I'don't have a clue how to use the coaxial spdif in for the stream at the same time. I tried different audio device settings, to stream the digital in, but with no success (plughw:0,1, iec958:0,0, dsnoop, dmix...).

Does anybody know how to detect the right device adress? Here are some more details:

```
root@audio:~# arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=Juli
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=Juli
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Juli,DEV=0
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Juli,DEV=0
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Juli,DEV=0
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Juli,DEV=0
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Juli,DEV=0
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Juli,DEV=0
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Juli,DEV=0
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Juli,DEV=0
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Juli,DEV=1
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724 IEC958
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Juli,DEV=0
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Juli,DEV=1
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724 IEC958
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Juli,DEV=0 of different also-tool outputs:
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Juli,DEV=1
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724 IEC958
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Juli,DEV=0
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Juli,DEV=1
    ESI Juli@, ICE1724 IEC958
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

cat /proc/asound/cards

```
root@audio:~# cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Juli           ]: ICE1724 - ESI Juli@
                      ESI Juli@ at 0xc0e0, irq 10
```

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: The bureaucratic name for S/PDIF is IEC958; you want one of the `DEV=1` devices.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Sounds like another round of time killing experiments ;-). Unfotunately I'm now off for a while, but I will post my results when I'm back.

Comment: It's been a while since my question, but I just want to give a little update. It seem like there are some driver issues with this soundcard causing the digital in not work properly with alsa. I'm just keep working on it, but until now without success.